Which word should we use to fill in "...thousands of port workers from across the country _ going on strike hours ago...."?
From Thousands of dock workers go on strike, possibly affecting grocery prices 0:02:

Following breaking news this morning, thousands of port workers from
across the country going on strike hours ago.

Should we use "start" ? But Cambridge has the definition:

to start to strike:

In 'start going on strike', 'start' seems to clash with the 'go on strike'.

Unless people are familiar with US broadcast news coverage, they will not understand this usage which is perfectly normal in that type of coverage.

The expression is to go on strike. So it's go that you modify.
In your example, it already happened, so it's the simple past:

Following breaking news this morning, thousands of port workers from across the country went on strike hours ago.

You can use the perfect tense, but you have to eliminate the last part of the sentence:

Following breaking news this morning, thousands of port workers from across the country have gone on strike hours ago.


can we use "was going on strike"?

No, because it already happened (and the subject "workers" is plural). You can say "Following breaking news this morning, thousands of port workers from across the country were going to strike," but that's a different meaning completely.

Not in American broadcast journalism where they use the ing verb forms without an auxiliary. Go listen to David Muir on ABC News Tonight. He uses this form all the time.

"thousands of port workers was going on strike?"  all the time?

No, obviously, it would be: are going on strike. are. Yes, leaving out is or are in action verbs is common in this US broadcast style.

First of all, recognize that closed captions can contain mistakes and don't necessarily reflect the exact wording or punctuation of the original. I think there's a word missing, just barely audible at the beginning of the video, that changes things: "We're following breaking news this morning: thousands..." So the entire phrase starting with "thousands" is not its own independent clause; rather the "going" is the news, and the main verb of the sentence is "following." This also helps it make sense; without it, it would sound like the striking happened "following" [after] the news, as if in response to it.

So,"thousands of port workers from across the country _ going on strike hours ago"? What word should be in the gap? Is it a present participle with past time adjunct?

@Mr.Wang None; it doesn't have to be a clause at all. It's a phrase that is describing or identifying the "news." A very simplified version of this sentence would be "We're reporting about some news: workers going on strike." (I'm not suggesting that this is a great way of wording it; I think making a new sentence would have been better. Just that this seems like the best explanation of what they were saying.)

This is not from closed captions. You can hear the presenter saying it without the "is".

@Lambie "Is"? I feel like I hear an "r" sound before "following," thus my guess of "we're." (And yeah, I guess there's no evidence that the OP had CC on; I happened to and it gives "Following" with capital "f") On re-listening just now, it's clear that something precedes "following," but I'm not certain what; it has an open vowel-like quality, but could even have been "...the following breaking news."

@AndyBonner I'm not arguing this. The use of the ing form is well attested in American broadcast journalism. The lady on the left says the sentence as posted by the OP, no doubt about it or what I have said re the verbING form. The OP wants to say: start going on strike. And that is not what the lady said. CC is not relevant here as you can hear her saying the sentence.

@Lambie Oh, I understand now, you're contesting the assertion that there's a preceding word. I started an answer at first along your lines, saying it amounted to headlinese, deleting a verb, and kind of functioned as a "spoken headline" to the report that followed. I'm pretty sure I hear the end of a preceding word, though.

@AndyBonner Right, it's spoken headlinese. And in that posted sentence, it is exactly like the woman says it. Exactly.

In news coverage in the US (I have not noticed this on BrE channels), news presenters (especially on channels like ABC) often skip using the full present continuous (be + verbING) and just use the present participle form instead:

Following breaking news this morning, thousands of port workers from across the country going on strike hours ago.

It is standard fare with some broadcasters.
David Muir from ABC news
Keep watching until he mentions Kamala Harris. He says "campaigning" tonight instead of "is campaigning".
Andy Bonner has used the term: spoken headlinese. Yes, it's like that.

So, the complete sentence should be "thousands of port workers from across the country wew going on strike hours ago"?

@Mr.Wang Yes, are going strike.
